# How to associate multiple Doctrine objects in a foreach loop before flushing the entity manager

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

i need your help for persist data, i explain :
i have entity Player with variable refer Team :

```
class DataPlayer
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Team")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tag_team", referencedColumnName="tag_team")
     */
    private $team;
    ...
}
```

but when i include the data, i have only tag of team, not entity team...
because the team is not probably present in database (i include team after).
how can i do to set team with string (the tag directly) whitout to change Entity player

thank!

Comment: As much as I deal with Doctrine and Symfony2 on a daily basis, I can't understand your question.

Comment: I would do this:$dataP = new DataPlayer(); $dataP->setTeam($tag)); $tag is string !

Comment: You have to set a `Team` object to the `setTeam()` function. If the Team doesn't exist yet... you have to create it!

Comment: the team is creat and persist before but not flush ! and i have no access to team object when i set team

Comment: Please show your code for the controller action function, including the functions that create/persist the Team objects

Comment: arff code is too long ^^

Comment: Then I can't help you. Post in a Gist or Pastebin, or post accurate snippets of your functions.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Gf8UH45n see here...

Comment: In terms of the `foreach` loop, that looks pretty good actually. What errors are you getting?

Comment: team of player is null in database because if i set team with $info[4] error -> string given, (entity Team expected), yet in database this is tag save...

Comment: Why are you removing your pastebin code? Now I can't go back to it and line up what you're talking about with the code

Comment: expiration ... i repaste http://pastebin.com/7uLi7r1P

Comment: Where in the code are you using `$info[4]`? You're still not making any sense.

Comment: $dataJ->setTeam(!!!! TEAM !!!!!); ideally $info[4] but not works ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I believe I see what you're trying to achieve.

You are doing some sort of import, and during the `foreach` loop, you're creating `Team` entities that get associated with your `DataPlayer`. Obviously you don't want to end up making multiple Teams after the first one has been made with a certain tag, but since you haven't performed a `flush()` using the Entity Manager yet, you can't `findOneByTag()` because the Team doesn't yet exist in the database.

This is obviously problematic. So what's the solution? Create a temporary array!

```
$tempTeams = array();
foreach($teams as $team){
    $info = explode(',', str_replace("'", "", $team));
    if (isset($tempTeams[$info[1]])) {
        $db_team = $tempTeams[$info[1]];
    } else {
        $db_team = $db->getRepository("ApplicationTestBundle:Team")->findOneByTag($info[1]);
    }
    if(!$db_team){
        $db_team = new Team();
        $db_team->setTag($info[1]);
        $db_team->setName($info[0]);
        $em->persist($db_team);
        $tempTeams[$info[1]] = $db_team;
    }
    $dataT = new DataTeam();
    $dataT->setTeam($db_team);
    $em->persist($dataT);
    $db_team = false; // Need to make sure $db_team is cleared out for the next iteration of the foreach
}
```

This takes all of your temporary PHP objects before persistence and buffers it into the temporary array, which allows you to recall your new Objects by tag name with no problems. The other solution is to `$em->flush();` after `$em->persist($db_team);`

You can then access the `$tempTeams` array for later lookups (I believe there was an issue with using `$info[4]` for the tag this time):

```
foreach($players as $player){
    $info = explode(',', str_replace("'", "", $player));
    $db_player = $db->getRepository("ApplicationTestBundle:Player")->findOneByPseudo($info[1]);
    $dataJ = new DataPlayer();
    $dataJ->setJoueur($db_player);
    if (isset($tempTeams[$info[4]])) {
        $db_team = $tempTeams[$info[4]];
    } else {
        $db_team = $db->getRepository("ApplicationTestBundle:Team")->findOneByTag($info[4]);
    }
    $dataJ->setTeam($db_team);  
    $em->persist($dataJ);
    $db_team = false;
}
```